# How to avoid type-casing

Tags: scala

**Note: this is a question about type-casing, not type-casting.  Please stop changing the title.**

I want to write a generic function `retrieve[F]` which returns a `List[F]` based on the `F` specified at runtime:

```
trait Foo
trait Bar extends Foo
trait Baz extends Foo

def retrieve[F <: Foo](implicit m: Manifest[F]): List[F] = m.erasure match {
  case x if x.isAssignableFrom(classOf[Bar]) => List[Bar]().asInstanceOf[List[F]]
  case x if x.isAssignableFrom(classOf[Baz]) => Nil
  case _ => Nil
}
```

Is there a more type-safe way to do this (i.e. without resorting to the manifest, `isAssignableFrom`, and casting each return value as `List[F]`)?

Comment: Updated with an example of casting.

Comment: I guess you can avoid it by reverting your last edit then. What is the point?

Comment: The point of the edit is to show that casting is needed for non-`Nil` return values.

Comment: Good idea to use another way to write `Nil` then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing this using type classes.  No loss of type information, and no need for type casing (or type casting).

The only weird bit I can see is choosing to pimp `retrieve` on to the `Bar` and `Baz` classes directly, but it seems to do the trick.

```
trait Foo
case class Bar(x: String) extends Foo
case class Baz(x: String) extends Foo

trait Retrievable[A] {
  def retrieve: List[A]
}

val _bars: List[Bar] = List(Bar("bar a"),Bar("bar b"))
val _bazs: List[Baz] = List(Baz("baz 1"),Baz("baz 2"))

implicit def barsRetrievable(x: Class[Bar]): Retrievable[Bar] =
  new Retrievable[Bar] {
    override def retrieve: List[Bar] = _bars
  }

implicit def foosRetrievable(x: Class[Baz]): Retrievable[Baz] =
  new Retrievable[Baz] {
    override def retrieve: List[Baz] = _bazs
  }

val bars: List[Bar] = classOf[Bar].retrieve
// bars: List(Bar(bar a), Bar(bar b))

val bazs: List[Baz] = classOf[Baz].retrieve
// bazs: List(Baz(baz 1), Baz(baz 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to eliminate the cast is by using an existential type:

```
trait Foo
trait Bar extends Foo
trait Baz extends Foo                                       

case object Bar1 extends Bar                                
case object Baz1 extends Baz                                

def retrieve[F <: Foo](implicit m: Manifest[F]): List[_ <: Foo] = m.erasure match {
  case x if x.isAssignableFrom(classOf[Bar]) => List[Bar]()  
  case x if x.isAssignableFrom(classOf[Baz]) => Nil  
  case _ => Nil
}
```

Unfortunately there still seems to be some loss of type information, since it isn't known at compile-time which `Foo` implementation will be returned:

```
val foos: List[Foo] = retrieve[Bar]                         
// val bars: List[Bar] = retrieve[Bar] // does not compile
```